# Questions closed as duplicates of a question with an unclear answer

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Sometimes questions are closed as a duplicate of a question with an answer that isn't as clear as it could be.

If this is the case, should new answers be posted as another answer on the original question? Or should the closed question be reopened and answers posted there?

For example: [Add a pause to an animated camera (following curve path)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33092/add-a-pause-to-an-animated-camera-following-curve-path)

If answers are added to the old question, all the answers stay in one place, however the answers will likely be conflicted in trying to address the nuances of the new question while acting as an answer to the original question.

If answers are added to the new question, answers are split into separate posts, but the answers stay where the action is and are free to address the OP's *exact* situation directly. Plus any comment discussions with the new question's OP will be in a more relevant location.

Which is preferred?

Answer (score 2):

If the questions really are duplicities, and the first answer(s) are not sufficient, then yes by all means add another answer to the original question.
However, there *should* be no reason to reopen the dup.

This applies to more then just dup questions, any time you find a question with a less then satisfactory answer, either edit it (if the changes are not too large) or add another answer.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understood.. I'm wondering *where* the new answers should go. On the new (closed) question? Or on the old (original) question?

Comment: @gandalf3 edited for better clarity.